# From where I can download Turbo C++ setup

Tags: c++, installation

From where I can download Turbo C++ setup, the one with blue srceen which we used in our academics..

Comment: Available open source on Microsoft codeplex for 32/64 bit https://turboc.codeplex.com

Comment: The link has been changing through the years, based on who hosts it. But it's been traditionally "1st google search result" [how to download turbo c](https://youtu.be/05A6fJ_HRIQ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [museum](http://dn.codegear.com/article/21751) (legal)